# Pull Specific INC or CR from ServiceNow via Powershell

Tags: xml, api, powershell, servicenow

I am just trying to pull an Incident or a Change Request and its details from ServiceNow based off of its sys_id or number via powershell. I dont even know where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: ServiceNow has [many ways to get that data](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Web_Services#gsc.tab=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ServiceNow exposes a standard REST API for every table in the platform. Here are the docs for the [ServiceNow Table API](https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/rest_api_doc?v=geneva&id=r_TableAPI-GET). If you want to retrieve a specific Incident record, you would issue a `GET` request to the following endpoint:

`https://instancename.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident/{incident_sys_id}`

You can use this in combination with PowerShell's [Invoke-RestMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) cmdlet to actually pull the details. Example:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$uri = 'https://instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident/{incident_sys_id}'
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Credential $cred
```

Similar results can be achieved for any table in the system by changing the table portion of the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this project in GitHub:

https://github.com/Sam-Martin/servicenow-powershell

Comment: This works, but since it is for my company I have to have any module downloaded to come from a verified/trusted party such as ServiceNow themselves. Thank you though!

Comment: You could at least use his code as a starting point to writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I ended up needing to pull by number rather than sys_id because it was easier to get end user input via the INC number. Because of this though, I needed to do things a little differently.

```
$SNowUser = “YOURuserid”
$SNowPass = ConvertTo-SecureString –String “yourpasswordgoeshere”  –AsPlainText -Force
$SNowCreds = New-Object –TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential –ArgumentList $SNowUser, $SNowPass
$headers = @{
Accept = “application/json”
}
$body = @{   #Create body of the POST request
number='INC1234567'
}
$bodyJson = $body | ConvertTo-Json
$go = Invoke-RestMethod -Credential $SNowCreds -Headers $headers -Method GET -Uri “https://yourenvironment.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident” -Body $body -ContentType “application/json”
```

For newbies like me I thought this might help. This is what helped lead to my answer:

*When the input is a GET request, and the body is an IDictionary (typically, a hash table), the body is added to the URI as query parameters. For other request types (such as POST), the body is set as the value of the request body in the standard name=value format*

Hope this helps someone!